# Javascript accumulated result of applying the max operator to all elements

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite a `python` code for calculating accumulated result of `max`. I refered to numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html)

Input:
`[7200,7050,7300,7500,7440,7200,7300,7280,7400]`

Output:
`[7200, 7200, 7300, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500, 7500]`

I understand that I can do it in a loop, but I'm looking for a compact, one-line solution if possible

Comment: So what did you try? Great that you want it to be one line, but did you accomplish it was multiple lines?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this is inline, more or less:

```js
var max = 0;
var input = [7200, 7050, 7300, 7500, 7440, 7200, 7300, 7280, 7400];
var output = input.map(function(e) {
  return max > e ? max : max = e;
});
console.log(output);
```

Inspired by [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51361720/2959522), here's another one line solution with map

```js
var input = [7200, 7050, 7300, 7500, 7440, 7200, 7300, 7280, 7400];
var output = input.map(function(e, i) {
  return Math.max(...input.slice(0, i + 1))
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution with `Array.from()` :

```js
var arr = [7200, 7050, 7300, 7500, 7440, 7200, 7300, 7280, 7400];
var output = Array.from({length:arr.length}, (el,i) => Math.max(...arr.slice(0,i+1)))
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner alternative:

```
a = [7200,7050,7300,7500,7440,7200,7300,7280,7400]

b = [max(a[0:i]) if i > 0 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: Take care because comprehension list have started to be removed in newer version of browsers : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions

Comment: Oh scratch that. I thought he wanted the python version... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Haha, I didn't event pay attention you used len and range and methods and that was actually Python code.